# How to Reassign a Variable in a Function That Uses Arguments in the Reassignment Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been working on a simple program that can convert Fahrenheit to Kelvin to Celsius.

It's a three-way converter(This means to me: It can convert f-c,c-k,f-k,etc.)

**Problem**: no matter what I pass to the function,input I always get 0.0.

I believe it has something to do with the variables reassignments, but it could be anything. Please help.

```
def temp_con(x, y, z):

    con_product = 0.0

    if x == 'f' or x == 'fahrenheit':
        if y == 'c' or y == 'celsius':
            con_product += (z - 32.0)/1.8
        elif y == 'k' or y == 'kelvin':
            con_product += (z + 459.67)/1.8
    elif x == 'c' or x == 'celsius':
        if y == 'f' or y == 'fahrenheit':
            con_product += z * 1.8 + 32.0
        elif y == 'k' or y == 'kelvin':  
            con_product += z + 273.15
    elif x == 'k' or x == 'kelvin':
        if y == 'c' or y == 'celsius':
            con_product += z - 273.15
        elif y == 'f' or y == 'fahrenheit':
            con_product += z * 1.8 - 459.67
    print(con_product)

print(temp_con(input('from'), input('to'), input('val')))
```

Comment: The x argument is: convert from
The y argument is: convert into
The z argument is: convert value

Comment: Looks like the "from" and/or "to" don't contain what you think. If your program would start the calculation you would get a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does't return anything to its caller. Change the last line from

```
print(con_product)
```

to

```
return con_product
```

...and in your code that calls this function:

```
print(temp_con(input('from'), input('to'), input('val')))
```

, you'll need to convert that last `z` argument from a string (which is what the `input()` function always returns) to a `float` before calling `temp_con()`.

I'd probably make that code more explicit, something like:

```
from = input('from')
to = input('to')
inputVal = float(input('value'))

converted = temp_con(from, to, inputVal)
print(converted)
```

...and once you've got that you can do things like handling errors sensibly -- what if someone enters `1, z, baloney` as the three parameters?

Comment: Where would I convert it at? I wouldn't convert it in the parameters, so would I go throughout the code and type float(z) instead of just z?

Comment: @michael2103: You could do `z = float(z)` as the first line in your function, so you don't have to convert it everywhere else. Of course the much better way would be to call the function with correct parameters.

Comment: would also strongly recommend using better names for your variables - from, to and value would be far better than x, y, z - would make your code much more readable.